# Binary Search in Java using Array of object name field

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm having an issue with binary search.

It works the first time through but if the user chooses this option from the menu it doesn't work for a resort not in the array, and sometimes doesn't work at all.  I can't figure out why it isn't working.  I've been reading different threads here to try and figure it out but am stumped.

EDIT: i think i got it working. i took out the entire portion of code and rewrote it over the only difference looking at the final results is the brackets in the if else if statement

```
                    if (resorts[middle].getName().compareTo(getDataFor) > 0)
                    {
                        high = middle - 1;
                    }
                    else if (resorts[middle].getName().compareTo(getDataFor) < 0)
                    {
                        low = middle + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resorts[middle].display();
                        found = true;
                    }
```

Thank you for the help!

```
  else if (choice == '2')
        {
            found = false;
            while (!found)
            {    
                System.out.print("Which resort would you like data for?: ");
                getDataFor = kb.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                low = 0;
                high = resorts.length;
                while (low <= high && !found)
                {
                    middle = (high + low) / 2;
                    if (resorts[middle].getName().compareTo(getDataFor) > 0)
                        high = middle - 1;
                    else if (resorts[middle].getName().compareTo(getDataFor) < 0)
                        low = middle + 1;
                    else
                    {
                        resorts[middle].display();
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                    System.out.println("Resort not found, please try again.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the array is sorted before using the binary search?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What behavior do you see?

Comment: the array is sorted. by doesn't work it either says it can't find the resort when it is in the array or I enter the resort i am looking for and press enter but nothing happens from there and says the program is still running

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `low` to `-1`, not zero, and on each non-match set `low` or `high` to `middle` without adding or subtracting anything.

Visualize `low` and `high` as pointing to entries that have already been examined and could not possibly be a match.  You start both one element "outside" the array.  When `middle` proves not to be the match, it replaces `low` or `high` as the outer bound of entries that cannot possibly match.

Or, you could write the code with `low` and `high` representing the "inside bounds" of the candidate range, in which case your `middle-1` and `middle+1` would be correct, and initial conditions would be `low=0` and `high=length-1`.

You can choose either visualization, but your starting conditions (`low` and `high` values) are inconsistent.

Comment: i tried both of these solutions and neither seemed to work. The first suggestion the I enter the resort i'm searching for and it just runs and never does anything else, the second solution will only find the middle value but no others

Comment: You have to either step through the code in a debugger or insert debug logging statements to follow what's happening. Print out `high`, `low` and `middle` on each iteration.  The problem should then become obvious.